# jetty.state issue when starting Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

I rent a CentOS 6 VPS and wish to install Jetty on it so I can use Solr for a project I've been working on.

I've been following [this jetty tutorial](http://www.copper-arrow.com/blog/jetty-web-server-centos-6) to install Jetty on my VPS, however when I try to start Jetty using `service jetty start` or `/etc/init.d/jetty start` I receive the following error(s):

```
Starting Jetty: grep: /var/run/jetty.state: No such file or directory
grep: /var/run/jetty.state: No such file or directory
grep: /var/run/jetty.state: No such file or directory
FAILED Sat Apr 20 00:21:56 BST 2013
```

I've looked in the logs and it doesn't look like anything is added to them regarding more information about this error. This is what my Jetty config file looks like:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin
JAVA=$JAVA_HOME/java
JAVA_OPTIONS=" -server -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC "
JETTY_HOME=/srv/jetty
JETTY_USER=jetty
JETTY_PORT=7070
JETTY_HOST=localhost
JETTY_LOGS=/srv/jetty/logs/
```

Has anyone experienced this before and can point me in the right direction as to what I need to do to resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

After hitting this problem, I found that `jetty.state` must be writable to the java process. So if you are not running jetty as root, `/var/run` will not be writable and you'll have this problem.

My solution is to create a directory where jetty can write, like `/opt/jetty/run` and put it into `/etc/default/jetty` file:

```
JETTY_RUN=/opt/jetty/run/
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the tutorial at
http://www.copper-arrow.com/blog/jetty-web-server-centos-6

1. in `/etc/init.d/jetty` or `/srv/jetty/bin/jetty.sh` find and replace a string

   ```
   rm -f $JETTY_STATE
   ```

   to

   ```
   #rm -f $JETTY_STATE
   ```
2. in terminal:

   service jetty supervise

   after several seconds press Ctrl+C and than

   service jetty restart

Comment: Didn't help me. Jetty 9.0.2